# In ExtJs, how to insert a fixed string at caret position in a TextArea?

Tags: javascript, extjs, textarea

This question probably is asked in other framework, not sure if there is one on ExtJs, which I am new to. I wonder whether there is a simple example with a TextArea and a button. When the button is pressed, a fixed string "???" is inserted at the cursor in the TextArea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually do this straight from the DOM, using textareas selectionStart attribute to find the caret position.

So you could do something along the lines of

```
textArea.value = textArea.value.substring(0, selectionStart)+'???'+textArea.value.substring(selectionStart);
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8LXnA/1/) demonstrating this using a combination of Ext.get and Ext.getDom to select and modify the elements.

Comment: Thanks Kieran for the reply. It works great! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In extjs 7.5.1 (maybe older), you can get the cursor position with the getCaretPos() method of the textArea object :

```
    var textToInsert = 'test';
    var txtArea = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#yourTextAreaItemId')[0];
    var currentContent = txtArea.getValue();
    var caretPos = txtArea.getCaretPos();

    txtArea.setValue(currentContent.substring(0,caretPos) + textToInsert + currentContent.substring(caretPos));
```

**Beware that this method does not seem to be documented in the framework docs so beware of possible updates.**